# Why does aov consider a 3x3 factorial design unbalanced?

Tags: r, anova, experiment-design

I have a two factor, bot at 3 levels with all factor levels, and with 5 replicates for each. This is a standard 3^2 factorial design, and yet aov gives the message "Estimated effects may be unbalanced". Why?

My commands are:

balanced.data <- read.table('balanced_data.txt',header=TRUE)
anova2        <- aov(Time~Fat*Milk,data=balanced.data)
print(anova2)

And my data is:

Fat  Milk   Time
Fat30   Kirnu   71.2
Fat30   Kirnu   68
Fat30   Kirnu   74.5
Fat30   Kirnu   75.2
Fat30   Kirnu   78
Fat33   Kirnu   57.5
Fat33   Kirnu   56.2
Fat33   Kirnu   50.9
Fat33   Kirnu   53.5
Fat33   Kirnu   51.5
Fat35   Kirnu   47.4
Fat35   Kirnu   46.7
Fat35   Kirnu   45.7
Fat35   Kirnu   51.5
Fat35   Kirnu   46.5
Fat30   Kuorittu    79.3
Fat30   Kuorittu    84.8
Fat30   Kuorittu    95.4
Fat30   Kuorittu    90.6
Fat30   Kuorittu    72.1
Fat33   Kuorittu    55.4
Fat33   Kuorittu    53.7
Fat33   Kuorittu    58.5
Fat33   Kuorittu    60.08
Fat33   Kuorittu    55.3
Fat35   Kuorittu    52
Fat35   Kuorittu    50.4
Fat35   Kuorittu    48.8
Fat35   Kuorittu    45.3
Fat35   Kuorittu    52.4
Fat30   Prot.suod.  55.2
Fat30   Prot.suod.  54.4
Fat30   Prot.suod.  57.2
Fat30   Prot.suod.  60.5
Fat30   Prot.suod.  52.4
Fat33   Prot.suod.  52.7
Fat33   Prot.suod.  54.3
Fat33   Prot.suod.  51.1
Fat33   Prot.suod.  47.5
Fat33   Prot.suod.  48.1
Fat35   Prot.suod.  51
Fat35   Prot.suod.  43.01
Fat35   Prot.suod.  50
Fat35   Prot.suod.  45.4
Fat35   Prot.suod.  48.3